# After iOS 8 UIView animation does not work. If something other has changed on the screen, UIView position is reset

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have an old application which has an UIView, a mercury. Whenever a negative or positive vote happens, it should change its state on a benchmark from 0-100, showing the current vote standing. The problem is when I change something else on the screen, for example a text in a label, the position of the mercury is reseted to its original position (which is determined in the .xib file).

It worked perfectly in iOS 7.

```
@property(nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mercury;

-(IBAction)happyBtn:(id)sender
{
    self.counter++;
    self.positiveVotes++;
    if(self.show!=NO){
        [self newPosition:YES];
    }else{
        [self newPosition:NO];
    }
}

-(IBAction)peekBtn:(id)sender
    {
        if(self.peekCounter!=0){
            self.peekCounter--;
// * if I comment this out, the mercury's position is reseted
            //[self.peekLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Available peeks: %d",self.peekCounter ]];
            [self newPosition:YES];
        }else{
            UIAlertView *alertV = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No more peeks" message:@"No more peeks available" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertV show];
        }
    }

 -(void)newPosition:(BOOL)show
{

        CGFloat mod = 100/self.counter;
        self.pos = mod *self.positiveVotes;
        self.fpos = 400- ((300/100)*self.pos);
        NSLog(@"counter:%f, positive:%f, mod:%f pos:%f, fpos:%f",self.counter,self.positiveVotes,mod,self.pos,self.fpos);
        CGRect mercurybox = self.mercury.frame;
        mercurybox.origin.y = self.fpos;


        if(show==YES){

            self.mercury.frame = mercurybox;
            //self.tipLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f",self.pos];

        }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some autolayout constraints that might be working against you? If you are using autolayout you should move your view by changing the constraints rather than changing the frame.

Comment: I turned of "Use Auto Layout" and now everything works fine! :)) Thanks!!!